# How to debug scikit classifier that chooses wrong class with high confidence

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I am using the LogisticRegression classifier to classify documents. The results are good (macro-avg. f1 = 0.94). I apply an extra step to the prediction results (predict_proba) to check if a classification is "confident" enough (e.g. >0.5 confidence for the first class, >0.2 distance in confidence to the 2. class etc.). Otherwise, the sample is discarded as "unknown".

The score that is most significant for me is the number of samples that, despite this additional step, are assigned to the wrong class. This score is unfortunately too high (~ 0.03). In many of these cases, the classifier is very confident (0.8 - 0.9999!) that he chose the correct class.

Changing parameters (C, class_weight, min_df, tokenizer) so far only lead to a small decrease in this score, but a significant decrease in correct classifications. However, looking at several samples and the most discriminative features of the respective classes, I cannot understand where this high confidence comes from. I would assume it is possible to discard most of these samples without discarding significantly more correct samples.

Is there a way to debug/analyze such cases? What could be the reason for these high confidence values?

Comment: Have you tried to scale your data with for example [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)?

Comment: @TomDLT I am using TF-IDF values for the text classification with L2 normalization, which should cover scaling the data.

Comment: I have a similar problem with image classification with CNTK. High confidence for wrong answers !!! and I still don't have the clue...